# Reducing fat content in thick chicken stock

Tags: chicken-stock, low-fat, thickness

My chicken stock is very gelatinous (good) but it didn't have a layer of fat to skim off.  How can I reduce the fat content?

Answer (score 21):

Gelatin and fat are different.  Chill your stock.  If a layer of fat solidifies at the surface, remove it.  If you see no layer of solidified fat, you've probably eliminated as much as possible.

Comment: I'm tempted to say 'keep the fat' (schmalz). It's useful, tasty stuff.

Comment: @RobinBetts absolutely!

Answer (score 1):

As it cools, the fat and water will separate into two layers, with the fat on top. If there is no/little fat layer, then there simply isn't any fat. The thickness that seems fatty is just gelatin that has set like jelly. That's a good thing as it means the stock was well made.

Answer (score -1):

To prevent gelatin from freezing, add more water. And excess fat can be removed by cooling the broth and collecting it on the surface.